# Move folders from azure containers which is having 2 levels of sub-folders to container level with the same name as the sub folder using ADF

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

There is a blob storage account, the name of the blob storage account is `azureblob11` it has a container with the name `source`.

The container `source` contains 2 level subfolders.

[image]

The folder structure looks similar:

```
source (container)
  |--a (folder)
     |--ana (sub-folder)
     |--hem (sub-folder)
     |--thg (sub-folder)
     |--oud (sub-folder)
```

The goal that I am trying to achieve is that copy all the subfolders (`ana, hem, thg, oud`) along with their data to the container level and create these 4 subfolders as new containers along with the data in them as is.

The expected goal looks like this:

```
source (container)
  |--a (folder)
     |--ana (sub-folder)
     |--hem (sub-folder)
     |--thg (sub-folder)
     |--oud (sub-folder)
ana (container)
hem (container)
thg (container)
oud (container)
```

To achieve this goal, I have used the `copy data` pipeline in ADF.
Selected the source.
Chose the source data set
-> select New
-> chosen the type as `Azure blob storage`
-> chosen the format as `binary`
-> chosen the linkeservice as `movecontainer`

[image]

Selected the sink
-> select New
-> chosen the type as `Azure blob storage`
-> chosen the format as `binary`

[image]

I am stuck on how to configure the parameters or the dynamic content for creating the containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Get Metadata` activity to get the list of **subfolder** names and pass it to `ForEach` activity to copy the folders to sink as shown below.

Source structure in **Azure data lake**:

[image]

A**DF pipeline:**

1. Using the `Get Metadata` activity, get the list of subfolder names under the folder “**a**” and container “**source**”.

   - Create a dataset for the source path and add it to the **Get Metadata dataset**.

[image]

•    Select **child items** under the field list in dataset properties.

[image]

•   **Output** of Get Metadata:

[image]

2. Pass this output to `ForEach` activity.

• Under **items** property, add Get Metadata output child items.

[image]

3. Add `Copy data` activity inside `ForEach` activity.

• Create **source dataset** and **parameterize** the subfolder (directory) path in the source dataset as shown below.

[image]

•   In `copy data` activity, pass **current ForEach item name** to the dataset parameter value in source properties.

[image]

•   Create **sink dataset** and parameterize the sink container path in the sink dataset.

[image]

•   In the `Copy activity` sink dataset, pass the current ForEach item name to the sink parameter.

[image]

4. Subfolders and files from each subfolder are copied to the sink. It **creates** a **sink container** with the current item name if does not exist.

[image]